# Make the column buffer independent in Putty

Tags: windows, putty, buffer

How can one set the horizontal scroll buffer in Putty so that it is different from the size of the window? For example, have the window only display 80 columns but the buffer hold 160 columns.

I know it's easy to do something similar for the rows by changing the `scrollback` buffer, but I have not been able to find a way to do this for the columns.

EDIT: According to [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/411934/how-to-change-the-number-of-columns-on-a-putty-window-to-more-than-the-screen-wi), it seems this feature was not available two years ago. Does anyone know if that is still the case?

EDIT2: If anybody knows of a simple way to get this feature by adding/enabling it in the Putty source code, I will be open to trying this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is still the case. Only other way is to change the "Columns" from the standard 80 to a number you want.

Comment: Thanks Victor! And just to follow up, there's no way to download the Putty source and easily enable such a feature in the source code, is there?